# How Can I Automate An Email With Excel?

Tags: excel, email, automation, odoo

I'm currently trying to automate some emails since I've been tasked with sending 430 emails to costumers of the company I work with.

I am working with Odoo for my contacts list, using a Mac and its subsequent Apple products to send the emails. I tried looking at some tutorials online but got stuck at "2. Read the excel field and store in dt1 3. Use for each row to loop through each rows of dt1." I am 100% new to Excel so I don't know what this means.

I have the names and emails of the customers ready in an excel file already, however, I don't know how to add in the subject line and body. The body needs to contain this line, "Good Morning/Afternoon, NAME_OF_CUSTOMER," I need a way to also automate the fill in.

These were the tutorials I was using:
https://forum.uipath.com/t/create-text-from-excel-info/263923
https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/send-email-formula-no-macros/

Any help appreciated, I really don't want to do all of this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this directly by Odoo.
Install "Email Marketing" Application in Odoo and select your contacts or import a CSV/XLS file in Newsletter Leads model.

Then you'll be able to create a campaign and massively send emails to your contacts.

You should first configure an SMTP server in Odoo via Settings -> Technical Features -> Out-bound email servers

Comment: A coworker said that sometimes mass emails end in the spam folder, how likely is that?

Comment: Depends on your SMTP reputation, take a look at this tool to check your sender reputation: https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability